# Family of linear independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $K \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z_{2}} \}$ (I want to show both cases), and $V$ vectorspace. I want to proof:
If the family of vectors $(u,v,w)$ is linear independent, then $(u+v,u+w,v+w)$  is linear independent.

Alright let's start for $\mathbb{R}$

Consider $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

$u,v,w$ are linear independent if and only if $au+bv+cw=0$ means that $a=b=c=0$.

$(u+v)\cdot a + (u+w) \cdot b +(v+w) \cdot c = 0$.

$\leftrightarrow ua+va+ub+wb+vc+wc = 0$

$\leftrightarrow u(a+b)+v(a+c)+w(b+c) = 0$

Since $u,v,w$ linear independent $(a+b)+(a+c)+(b+c) =0$, therefore  $(u+v,u+w,v+w)$ linear independent.

Now I want to look at the second case.

Consider $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z_2}$.

In my opinion, nothing changes since $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both fields. Am I missing something or is this proof valid if I just say that both of these are fields?

Comment: I think you mean to say "Since $u$,$v$,$w$ linearly independent, $(a+b)=(a+c)=(b+c)=0$". And you then need to convince me that this implies that $a=b=c=0$ to conclude that $(u+v,u+w,v+w)$ are independent.

Comment: Well, consider $(a+b) = (a+c ) = (b+c) \neq 0 $ then $u*x+v*y+w*z=0$ with $x=(a+b), y=(a+c), z =(b+c)$ We have that u,v,w linear independent, therefore $x=y=z = 0$ and therefore $(a+b) = (a+c ) = (b+c) = 0$. I'm confused now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far is
$$a+b=b+c=c+a=0\quad\ (1)$$
To obtain the result, you need to conclude $a=b=c=0$, which is easy in the case of $\Bbb R$:
Adding all three equations we get
$$2(a+b+c)=0\quad\ (2)$$
Therefore, *dividing by $2$*, we get $a+b+c=0$ and we can conclude.

In the case of characteristic $2$, however, division by $2$ is not allowed, as $2=1+1=0$.
And, indeed, $a=b=c=1$ is a solution for $(1)$, proving that $u+v,\,u+w,\,v+w$ are linearly *dependent* in this case.

Comment: This defininetly makes alot of sense.

So we know that there exists a case for which if we use $K = \mathbb{Z_2}$ is linearly dependent. I've tried to find a counterexample to this specific case to proof that it is indeed linearly dependent. I know that your answer defininetly is enough to show this but can you think of a specific set of vectors that could act as an counterexample?

Comment: Yes, just write the standard basis for $u,v,w$, i.e. vectors $(1,1,0),\ (1,0,1),\ (0,1,1)$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb F_2$: the sum of any two gives the third.